# ReSharper reorder String.Format() arguments

Tags: c#, resharper

I often find myself writing something daft like:

```
String.Format("{1}: {0}", reason, message);
```

or something similar but with far more string placeholders.

Is there an automated refactoring in ReSharper to change the order of the placeholders and the arguments? I have a tendency to mess up the mapping if I try to change the order by hand.

Obviously, the example above is trivial. What I am doing in reality is often writing something like:

```
String.Format("{0}.{2} = {1}.{3} AND {0}.{4} = {1}.{5} AND {6}.{7} = {1}.{8}",
  table1Alias, table2Alias, col1A, col2A, col1B, col2B, table3Alias, col3C, col2C);
```

and thinking to myself that it would be great if I could move table3Alias up to the front next to the other aliases.

(ReSharper 7.1.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such functionality.

Answer (score 4):

For C# 6+ (ReSharper 10+ / 2016+):

- Place your cursor at string.Format
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Select `Use string interpolation`
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> again
- Select `Convert to string.Format`

Comment: That's a sneaky way of doing it. But if I use C# 6, why would I even want `string.Format` anymore?

Answer (score 1):

Just place your cursor in table3Alias, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Left/Right arrow. This changes the parameter order in a function call.

There's also an option for removing one when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

[image]

There's also a shortcut to add a format item. You may be able to do what you want with combining these. The exact functionality you ask is not implemented.

Comment: That doesn't change the corresponding placeholder(s) in the string.

Comment: Nope, that changes the order of parameters. Isn't that what OP wants?

Comment: +1 for being a cool trick anyway, don't know how I didn't know about that

Comment: I wanted to change the order of the parameters and have the place holders keep in sync.

Comment: `string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", foo, bar, fubar)`. Put the cursor on `fubar` and hit Ctrl + Alt + Shift + Left. The result is: `string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", foo, fubar, bar)`. But the OP wants this: `string.Format("{0}, {2}, {1}", foo, fubar, bar)`

Comment: Yeah, ReSharper doesn't have it.